# no audio with playbin or autoaudiosink on gstreamer, but plays with alsasink

Tags: alsa, gstreamer, hifiberry

recently upgraded my raspian, and installation of RPi with Hifiberry AMP.

and my python application that utilizes gstreamer's api is no longer working.

as a test to figure out why I am using the gst-launcher tool and have the follow results:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! autoaudiosink  <-- no audio
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! alsasink <--- test tone is audible
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/pi/Music/01\ Hello.mp3   <--- no audio
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/pi/Music/01\ Hello.mp3 audio-sink=alsasink  <--- plays at mp3 file
```

my python application previously only setup the playbin pipeline.  It would appear gstreamer can no longer automatically select the alsasink as the correct output.

I have set the /etc/asound.conf to:

```
pcm.!default {
  type hw card 0
}
ctl.!default {
  type hw card 0
}
```

and ~/.asoundrc to:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

pcm.output {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

pcm.input {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

is there some other way to get the playbin pipeline to automatically select the alsasink output?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turned out it was because I have the packages gstreamer1.0-omx* installed, that include omxanalogaudiosink and omxhdmiaudiosink (audio via OMX chip without alsa involved):

```
gst-inspect-1.0 | grep -i audio | grep -i sink
omx:  omxanalogaudiosink: OpenMAX Analog Audio Sink
omx:  omxhdmiaudiosink: OpenMAX HDMI Audio Sink
autodetect:  autoaudiosink: Auto audio sink
alsa:  alsasink: Audio sink (ALSA)
...
```

They have a higher rank (and would be preferred) than alsaaudiosink:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 omxanalogaudiosink | grep -i rank
Rank                     primary + 1 (257)
gst-inspect-1.0 alsasink | grep -i rank
Rank                     primary (256)
```

So removing those packages should help.

(Using OMX sink I also got the error  `* failed to open vchiq instance`)